# Erro: Java.lang.StackOverflowError:, com like no hibernate(loop Query.getResultList())

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, hql

Estou com um método:

```
public static List<Texto> getTextoPorIdAlternativoLike(String idAlternativoTexto) {

    Texto texto = new Texto();

    String where = "t.idAlternativo like :idAlternativo";
    List<NameValuePair> whereParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    whereParameters.add(new NameValuePair("idAlternativo",
            idAlternativoTexto));

    List<Texto> result = texto.read(where, whereParameters);

    if (result == null) {
        result = new ArrayList<Texto>();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Quando chamo o método, chamo da seguinte forma:

```
List<Texto> listaTextos = getTextoPorIdAlternativoLike("1*casa-aberta" + "%");
```

E o método read() está da seguinte forma:

```
public List<T> read(String where, List<NameValuePair> whereParameters){


       initializeEntityManager();

       List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();


        boolean closeTransaction = false;
    try {
        if (!entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            logger.debug("\n*** Starting transaction \n");
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            closeTransaction = true;
        }           

        String hQl = "from " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " t ";
        // String hQl = "from T t ";
        System.out.println(hQl);
        if ((where != null) && (!where.trim().isEmpty())) {
            hQl += " where " + where;

            System.out.println(hQl);
        } 


        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hQl);

        if ((where != null) && (!where.trim().isEmpty())) {
            if (whereParameters != null) {
                for (NameValuePair par : whereParameters) {
                    logger.debug("Set attribute: " + par.getName());

                    query.setParameter(par.getName(), par.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        list = query.getResultList();

        if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            if (closeTransaction) {
                logger.debug("\n*** Commiting transaction \n");
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            if (closeTransaction) {
                logger.debug("\n*** Rollback transaction\n");
                entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        }

        throw e;

    } finally {
        if (closeTransaction) {
            logger.debug("\n*** Closing EM\n");
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

        return list;

}
```

A query gerada é:

> from Texto t  where (t.documentoFonte = :documentoFonte) and (t.idAlternativo like :idAlternativo) and (dataDesativacao is null)
>   2016-05-13 15:35:34 DEBUG ABeanDao:604 - HQL: 
>   2016-05-13 15:35:35 DEBUG ABeanDao:605 - from Texto t  where (t.documentoFonte = :documentoFonte) and (t.idAlternativo like :idAlternativo) and (dataDesativacao is null)
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:294 - parse() - HQL: from br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto t  where (t.documentoFonte = :documentoFonte) and (t.idAlternativo like :idAlternativo) and (dataDesativacao is null)
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:312 - --- HQL AST ---
>    -[QUERY] Node: 'query'
>       +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
>       |  -[FROM] Node: 'from'
>       |     -[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
>       |        +-[DOT] Node: '.'
>       |        |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
>       |        |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
>       |        |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
>       |        |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
>       |        |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'br'
>       |        |  |  |  |  |  -[IDENT] Node: 'com'
>       |        |  |  |  |  -[IDENT] Node: 'lexplena'
>       |        |  |  |  -[IDENT] Node: 'model'
>       |        |  |  -[IDENT] Node: 'documento'
>       |        |  -[IDENT] Node: 'Texto'
>       |        -[ALIAS] Node: 't'
>       -[WHERE] Node: 'where'
>          -[AND] Node: 'and'
>             +-[AND] Node: 'and'
>             |  +-[EQ] Node: '='
>             |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
>             |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 't'
>             |  |  |  -[IDENT] Node: 'documentoFonte'
>             |  |  -[COLON] Node: ':'
>             |  |     -[IDENT] Node: 'documentoFonte'
>             |  -[LIKE] Node: 'like'
>             |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
>             |     |  +-[IDENT] Node: 't'
>             |     |  -[IDENT] Node: 'idAlternativo'
>             |     -[COLON] Node: ':'
>             |        -[IDENT] Node: 'idAlternativo'
>             -[IS_NULL] Node: 'is null'
>                -[IDENT] Node: 'dataDesativacao'
>
> 2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG ErrorCounter:113 - throwQueryException() : no errors
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker:121 - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG FromElement:158 - FromClause{level=1} : br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto (t) -> texto0_
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG FromReferenceNode:77 - Resolved : t -> texto0_.idTexto
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG DotNode:666 - getDataType() : documentoFonte -> org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType(br.com.lexplena.model.documento.DocumentoFonte)
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG DotNode:625 - dereferenceShortcut() : property documentoFonte in br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto does not require a join.
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG DotNode:653 - Terminal getPropertyPath = [documentoFonte]
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG FromReferenceNode:77 - Resolved : t.documentoFonte -> texto0_.idDocumentoFonte
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG FromReferenceNode:77 - Resolved : t -> texto0_.idTexto
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG DotNode:666 - getDataType() : idAlternativo -> org.hibernate.type.StringType@44824d2a
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG FromReferenceNode:77 - Resolved : t.idAlternativo -> texto0_.idAlternativo
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG FromReferenceNode:77 - Resolved : {synthetic-alias} -> {synthetic-alias}
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG DotNode:666 - getDataType() : dataDesativacao -> org.hibernate.type.CalendarType@5efd28f7
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG FromReferenceNode:77 - Resolved : {synthetic-alias}.dataDesativacao -> texto0_.dataDesativacao
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker:125 - select : finishing up [level=1, statement=select]
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG HqlSqlWalker:671 - processQuery() :  ( SELECT ( FromClause{level=1} Texto texto0_ ) ( where ( and ( and ( = ( texto0_.idDocumentoFonte texto0_.idTexto documentoFonte ) ? ) ( like ( texto0_.idAlternativo texto0_.idTexto idAlternativo ) ? ) ) ( is null ( texto0_.dataDesativacao {synthetic-alias} dataDesativacao ) ) ) ) )
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG HqlSqlWalker:947 - Derived SELECT clause created.
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG JoinProcessor:187 - Using FROM fragment [Texto texto0_]
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker:129 - select >> end [level=1, statement=select]
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:281 - --- SQL AST ---
>    -[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (Texto)
>       +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{derived select clause}'
>       |  +-[SELECT_EXPR] SelectExpressionImpl: 'texto0_.idTexto as idTexto1_31_' {FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=t,role=null,tableName=Texto,tableAlias=texto0_,origin=null,columns={,className=br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto}}}
>       |  -[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'texto0_.binario as binario2_31_, texto0_.idCrawlerConfig as idCrawl21_31_, texto0_.dataCriacao as dataCria3_31_, texto0_.dataDesativacao as dataDesa4_31_, texto0_.idDocumentoFonte as idDocum22_31_, texto0_.idAlternativo as idAltern5_31_, texto0_.nodeNameAnterior as nodeName6_31_, texto0_.nodeNamePosterior as nodeName7_31_, texto0_.idNorma as idNorma23_31_, texto0_.ordemExibicao as ordemExi8_31_, texto0_.idParteDoTexto as idParte24_31_, texto0_.parteDoTextoInstancia as parteDoT9_31_, texto0_.posicao as posicao10_31_, texto0_.pronto as pronto11_31_, texto0_.regra as regra12_31_, texto0_.idSuperEstruturaTextual as idSuper25_31_, texto0_.idTextoAnterior as idTexto26_31_, texto0_.textoBruto as textoBr13_31_, texto0_.textoEditado as textoEd14_31_, texto0_.textoExibido as textoEx15_31_, texto0_.textoFonetico as textoFo16_31_, texto0_.textoPesquisavel as textoPe17_31_, texto0_.versaoAlteracao as versaoA18_31_, texto0_.vigenciaInicio as vigenci19_31_, texto0_.vigenciaTermino as vigenci20_31_'
>       +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[t], fromElementByTableAlias=[texto0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
>       |  -[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'Texto texto0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=t,role=null,tableName=Texto,tableAlias=texto0_,origin=null,columns={,className=br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto}}
>       -[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
>          -[AND] SqlNode: 'and'
>             +-[AND] SqlNode: 'and'
>             |  +-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
>             |  |  +-[DOT] DotNode: 'texto0_.idDocumentoFonte' {propertyName=documentoFonte,dereferenceType=UNKNOWN,getPropertyPath=documentoFonte,path=t.documentoFonte,tableAlias=texto0_,className=br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto,classAlias=t}
>             |  |  |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'texto0_.idTexto' {alias=t, className=br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto, tableAlias=texto0_}
>             |  |  |  -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'documentoFonte' {originalText=documentoFonte}
>             |  |  -[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=documentoFonte, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType(br.com.lexplena.model.documento.DocumentoFonte)}
>             |  -[LIKE] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: 'like'
>             |     +-[DOT] DotNode: 'texto0_.idAlternativo' {propertyName=idAlternativo,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=idAlternativo,path=t.idAlternativo,tableAlias=texto0_,className=br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto,classAlias=t}
>             |     |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'texto0_.idTexto' {alias=t, className=br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto, tableAlias=texto0_}
>             |     |  -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'idAlternativo' {originalText=idAlternativo}
>             |     -[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=idAlternativo, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.StringType@44824d2a}
>             -[IS_NULL] IsNullLogicOperatorNode: 'is null'
>                -[DOT] DotNode: 'texto0_.dataDesativacao' {propertyName=dataDesativacao,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=dataDesativacao,path={synthetic-alias}.dataDesativacao,tableAlias=texto0_,className=br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto,classAlias=t}
>                   +-[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}' {originalText={synthetic-alias}}
>                   -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'dataDesativacao' {originalText=dataDesativacao}
>
> 2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG ErrorCounter:113 - throwQueryException() : no errors
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:263 - HQL: from br.com.lexplena.model.documento.Texto t  where (t.documentoFonte = :documentoFonte) and (t.idAlternativo like :idAlternativo) and (dataDesativacao is null)
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:264 - SQL: select texto0_.idTexto as idTexto1_31_, texto0_.binario as binario2_31_, texto0_.idCrawlerConfig as idCrawl21_31_, texto0_.dataCriacao as dataCria3_31_, texto0_.dataDesativacao as dataDesa4_31_, texto0_.idDocumentoFonte as idDocum22_31_, texto0_.idAlternativo as idAltern5_31_, texto0_.nodeNameAnterior as nodeName6_31_, texto0_.nodeNamePosterior as nodeName7_31_, texto0_.idNorma as idNorma23_31_, texto0_.ordemExibicao as ordemExi8_31_, texto0_.idParteDoTexto as idParte24_31_, texto0_.parteDoTextoInstancia as parteDoT9_31_, texto0_.posicao as posicao10_31_, texto0_.pronto as pronto11_31_, texto0_.regra as regra12_31_, texto0_.idSuperEstruturaTextual as idSuper25_31_, texto0_.idTextoAnterior as idTexto26_31_, texto0_.textoBruto as textoBr13_31_, texto0_.textoEditado as textoEd14_31_, texto0_.textoExibido as textoEx15_31_, texto0_.textoFonetico as textoFo16_31_, texto0_.textoPesquisavel as textoPe17_31_, texto0_.versaoAlteracao as versaoA18_31_, texto0_.vigenciaInicio as vigenci19_31_, texto0_.vigenciaTermino as vigenci20_31_ from Texto texto0_ where texto0_.idDocumentoFonte=? and (texto0_.idAlternativo like ?) and (texto0_.dataDesativacao is null)
>   2016-05-13 15:35:37 DEBUG ErrorCounter:113 - throwQueryException() : no errors

Ocorre que acaba em loop infinito no `list = query.getResultList();` , estourando o erro, pois ele faz várias consultas ao banco:

> Java.lang.StackOverflowError:

Parte do Log do erro

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at java.nio.CharBuffer.arrayOffset(CharBuffer.java:986)
>       at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions(UTF_8.java:77)
>       at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.overflow(UTF_8.java:500)
>       at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:530)
>       at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:619)
>       at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:561)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
>       at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
>       at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
>       at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
>       at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
>       at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:181)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:257)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:201)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025)
>       at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
>       at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:244)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:215)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:140)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025)

Alguma solução?

Comment: O erro tem mais alguma coisa relevante?

Comment: @Douglas coloquei agora parte do log do erro se tiver cmo me auxiliar agradeceria

Comment: Rodando o debug que notei que era no medoto getResultList()

Comment: Está me parecendo que seu array estourou, ao invés de like, teste usando um =.

Comment: @Douglas e quando nao é com like roda normal

Comment: @Douglas testei com `=.` conforme indicou e não aceito o `.` aponta erro de `unexpected token:`

Comment: O "." era o término da frase, rsrs. É só o = mesmo.

Comment: @Douglas eu preciso do like, pois o atributo nao seria somente isso, seria mais completo, precisaria dos objetos que contenham no inicio do idAlternativo a String acima por isso passo como `"1*casa-aberta" + "%"` que vira `"1*casa-aberta%"`, entendeu.

Comment: Entendo, vou olhar. Qualquer coisa eu posto.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39747/discussion-between-tiago-ferezin-and-douglas).